# Format number as percent without trailing zeroes

Tags: python

Given an arbitrary number, what's the best way to format it to a percentage string without trailing zeroes?

For example:

```
0     => "0%"
0.03  => "3%"
0.035 => "3.5%"
0.3   => "30%"
0.35  => "35%"
1     => "100%"
1.5   => "150%"
```

Comment: If the linked duplicate isn't acceptable, you could multiply by 100, format as a regular number, strip trailing zeros and decimal points, and append a `%`

Comment: Why mark as duplicate? The answers there do not work for all the cases I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
def format(f):
    p = f * 100
    return f'{int(p)}%' if p == int(p) else f'{p}%'
```

Note: because of Python's slight misaccuracy with floating points, when you do `format(0.035)` it outputs `3.5000000000000004%`. To fix this, use:

```py
def format(f):
    p = round(f * 100, 10)
    return f'{int(p)}%' if p == int(p) else f'{p}%'
```

Now, we can test it:

```py
print(format(0))
print(format(0.03))
print(format(0.035))
print(format(0.3))
print(format(0.35))
print(format(1))
print(format(1.5))
```

Output:

```
0%
3%
3.5%
30%
35%
100%
150%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
def func(n):
    return "%g%%"%(n*100)


print(func(0))
print(func(0.03))
print(func(0.035))
print(func(0.3))
print(func(0.35))
print(func(1))
print(func(1.5))
```

OUTPUT

```py
0%
3%
3.5%
30%
35%
100%
150%
```